# Intersections of two decreasing convex functions

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two continuous functions with the same domain and both are decreasing and convex. I think at most can intersect two times. Is this correct?

Comment: Are they monotonically decreasing?

Comment: By "decreasing" do you  mean "strictly decreasing" and by "convex" do you mean "strictly convex"?

Comment: Yes, both strictly.

Comment: If we take $f = g$ ?

Comment: No, different functions.

Answer (score 3):

Quickie example.   Domain is $(-\infty,0)$, functions are
$$
f(x) = x^2-\sin(x),\qquad g(x) = x^2-\frac{\sin(2x)}{4}
$$
Show: $f'(x)<0, f''(x)>0$ for all $x \in (-\infty,0)$.  Intersect at least at all $\pi k$, where $k$ is a negative integer.

Comment: And, if we add $f'''(x)>0$ and $g'''(x)<0$?

Comment: What happens if you start with $2+\sin(x)$ and $2+\sin(2x)$ and integrate $4$ times?  (instead of $2$ times as in my answer.)

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand you, can you be more specific?. I have to make a correction, suppose $f'''(x)>0$ and $g'''(x)>0.$